# Mysterious phantom rm -i alias

Tags: macos, unix, zsh, zshrc

I'm using zsh on Mac OS 10.6.8.

So, all of a sudden one of my machines asks me for confirmation every time I rm.

Frankly, I hate this with an abiding passion. I've never had a problem with rm, and I don't need to debate the potentialities.

First thing I did was `which rm`, which reports `rm: aliased to rm -i`.

Now, I've hunted high and low for this alias. zshrc, .config (which I don't have), the default zshrc files: everywhere I can think of. No mention of aliasing rm anywhere.

Is there a simple way to determine where this alias is being configured? Or to list all locations where zsh might be looking for config lines?

Comment: Maybe most likely it comes from /etc/profile (because Apple decided it would be a good idea to make this a system-wide default)? The zsh manpage should list all files ZSh sources on startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's no way to know which startup file an alias has been configured from, sort of searching them yourself.

The Z-shell startup files can be found [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l9).

A comment for the question suggests `/etc/profile`; this is incorrect (unless you're sourcing it yourself), as `/etc/profile` is a Bourne-type shell startup file.

If you can't find the place it's sourced, you could [unset the alias [bottom paragraph]](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/zsh/alias.html) in `~/.zshrc`: `unset rm`. That should work provided it's done after the alias is set.